# Usage of 'skip' option in multi-row update

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I am new to NodeJs and tried to use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) to do all the requests to my PG database.
I want to be able to update columns dynamically, meaning sometimes I will update only two columns for a row, sometimes I will update all of them, etc ...
My input will be a JSON.

Since I want the endpoint to be able to update multiple rows, I tried using helpers namespace with [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html).

Here is my Javascript code (inspired from previous stackoverflow answers):

```
  /* logic for skipping columns: */
  const skip = c => !c.exists || c.value === undefined;
  
  /* all the columns of the table */
  const column_structure = new dbconfig.pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
  [ '?id',
    {name: 'firstname', skip}, 
    {name: 'surname', skip}, 
    {name: 'yob', skip}, // year of birth
    {name: 'defensive_skill', skip}, 
    {name: 'offensive_skill', skip}, 
    {name: 'login', skip}, 
    {name: 'password', skip}
  ],
     {table: 'players'});
```

Here is the JSON I am feeding to the endpoint :

```
[{
  "id" : 25,
  "firstname": "Stephen",
  "surname": "Harrison",
  "yob": 1991,
  "defensive_skill": 5,
  "offensive_skill": 3,
  "login": "harry",
  "password": "123456"
},
{
  "id": 26,
  "firstname": "Chris",
  "surname": "Jackson",
  "defensive_skill": 5,
  "offensive_skill": 4,
  "login": "chris",
  "password": "123456"
}
]
```

And here is the error :

```
Property 'yob' doesn't exist.
```

As you can see, in the second object of my array, I didn't specify the field 'yob'.
I was expecting that for the second object, all the columns will be updated except the 'yob'.
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you inserting into a table with columns or just a column of json/jsonb? Presumably if this is a table relation it will be telling you that the column `yob` isn't present and it will require adding.

Comment: @Lucas There are eight columns in total, when updating I want to be able to update each of these columns individually. 
There is no 'column of json/jsonb'.
I think my issue is more 'pg-promise' related.

Comment: Corrected invalid use of type [skipCB](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.skipCB), from `c => !c.exists || c === undefined;` to `c => !c.exists || c.value === undefined;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work, is because `skip` logic is only possible for single-row updates, as [documented in the API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html):

> Used by methods `update` (for a single object)...

Multi-row update syntax doesn't allow for any skipping logic, and so you need to provide a default value when the property is missing, like this:

```
{name: 'yob', skip, def: defaultValue}
```

`defaultValue` can be anything above, including `undefined`.

Alternatively, you can make use of property `init`, and return a value dynamically.

---

So in the code above, if you change the column declaration to this:

```
{name: 'yob', skip, def: null}
```

your `update` call will generate:

```
UPDATE "players" AS t SET "firstname"=v."firstname","surname"=v."surname","yob"=v."yob","defensive_skill"=v."defensive_skill","offensive_skill"=v."offensive_skill","login"=v."login","password"=v."password" FROM (VALUES(25,'Stephen','Harrison',1991,5,3,'harry','123456'),(26,'Chr
is','Jackson',null,5,4,'chris','123456')) AS v("id","firstname","surname","yob","defensive_skill","offensive_skill","login","password")
```

As you can see from the generated SQL, it is impossible to skip one column with such syntax, that's why `skip` is ignored for multi-row updates. You can see it however working, if you pass in one object at a time, but that's a different usage scenario than the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer, I will update a single row at a time, seems to be the most suitable solution for me, since I don't want to set a default/init value.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t , in the multi-row update scenario, is it possible to specify the "original value in table" (maybe using init cb) when the value to update is null || undefined?